# lsb-graphics in very bad inconsistent state

Tags: drivers, printing, dpkg, lsb-release

I was trying to install the printer driver for Brother HL-2280DW, but I had to stop it due to the printer not appearing to any of the PCs anymore. After I stopped it I noticed this error when I attempt to perform a `apt-get upgrade`.

Here's a snippet of what output I receive:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2,834 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: error processing package lsb-graphics (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 lsb-graphics
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Is it safe to just remove lsb-graphics forcefully and reinstall it? I though I should ask first instead.

**EDIT** I went ahead and removed it using `dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq` and then reinstalling it with `apt-get install`. Is there anything that I have to reconfigure, or is it fine as is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dpkg --remove` will keep config files, in contrast to `dpkg --purge`, so your config should still be there.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: At the time of answering, the question read "Is there anything that I have to reconfigure, or is it fine as is?". My answer just says "the latter, you should be all OK". What's wrong with that?

Comment: Thank you. The printer was working with the generic drivers Ubuntu had, but the scanner wouldn't work since Simple Scan doesn't support Brother scanners. I have to use Brother's driver for this. Jan and @LuísdeSousa , just a side question though, what commands should I run to ensure that no configuration or anything is wrong with my system from time to time? Still relatively new to Ubuntu.